# JQuery - how to apply a function only once to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have this:

```
<div id='container'>
</div>
<input type='button' id='newTest' value='new' />
```

And some JQuery/JavaScript:

```
$('#newTest').click( function() {
    var newDiv = "<div class='test'>Click Me</div>";
    $('#container').append(newDiv);
    apply_click();
});

function apply_click() {
    $('.test').click( function() {
        alert('clicked'); 
    });    
}
```

Each new 'test' div that gets created should alert when clicked on... but each time we create a new 'test' div the .click function is applied to all of them again which means if I click the 'new' button 3 times and then click the first 'Click Me' div, 3 'clicked' alerts pop in sequence...  The question is then: how can I cause the apply_click() function to only apply to elements it has not already been applied to...?

I'm thinking there may be a way to do it if I have apply_click() accept an argument that is a reference to the newly created element but I'm not sure how that would work.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGcwx

Comment: Use: `$('.test').off('click').on('click'...` got it ?

Comment: what I suggested worked? Want an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attaching a click event to everything selected by `$('.test')` each time you create a new element, which is every element that has that class, including those you've already appended.

Why not use event delegation, which will allow you to bind a single event handler once?

```
$('#container').on('click', '.test', function(e){ ... });
```

All clicks on `.test` elements will bubble up to `#container` and you can handle them there.

Comment: This works nicely and seems to be an elegant solution however I'm not sure I'm understanding exactly why it's working... Any chance you could elaborate a bit?

Comment: Here are a couple resources that explain how event bubbling works: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html and http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/. Those resources should explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up is that every time you create a new element, a new click handler is applied to *all* `.test` elements. Pass the specific element into the `apply_click()` function so that it applies *only* to the new div.

```
$('#newTest').click( function() {
    var newDiv = $("<div class='test'>Click Me</div>");
    $('#container').append(newDiv);
    apply_click(newDiv);
});

function apply_click(element) {
    $(element).click( function() {
        alert('clicked'); 
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new jQuery object, then after appending it, then bind the click to that object, not the entire class.

```
$('#newTest').click(function () {
    var newDiv = $("<div class='test'>Click Me</div>");
    $('#container').append(newDiv);
    newDiv.click(apply_click)
});
function apply_click() {
    alert('clicked');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to use the one method:

`$('#newTest').one("click", function() {
    var newDiv = "<div class='test'>Click Me</div>";
    $('#container').append(newDiv);
    apply_click();
});`

The .one() method is identical to .on(), except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation. http://api.jquery.com/one/